# Java script button vs link to submit?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function called save changes and it looks like this

```
function saveChanges() {
  var theCity = city.value;
  var theState = state.value;
  var theEmail = email.value;
  var theAge = age.value;
  var theGender = gender.value;
  var theOther = other.value;
    alert("theCity is: "+ theCity);
    alert("theState is: "+ theState);
    alert("theEmail is: "+ theEmail);
    alert("theAge is: "+ theAge);
    alert("theGender is: "+ theGender);
    alert("theOther is: "+ theOther);
}
window.onload=function (){
    document.getElementById('ok').onclick=saveChanges;

}
```

and I have a simple html page multiple inputs on it.

To submit the content, I have a link at the bottom.

```
<a href="#" id="ok" style="color:white;">Click here <-- </a>
```

I have made a button with the same id='ok' and it does not work.

What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing a proper description of "does not work". What happens? Are there errors in console? What is the button's code?

Comment: Of course it would not work, `id` is supposed to be unique within the document.

Comment: Also you're missing the code for your button.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this,

## HTML

```
<form onsubmit="return validate(this)" method="POST" action="a_post_page.php">
    name: <input type="text" name="name" /> <br />
    email: <input type="text" name="email" /> <br />
    age: <input type="text" name="age" /> <br />
    gender: <input type="text" name="gender" /> <br />
    city: <input type="text" name="city" /> <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="Save" />
</form>
```

## Javascript

```
function validate(form1) {  
    if(form1.name.value === "") {  
        alert("Please type your name the name feild.");  
        return false;  
    }  
    if(form1.email.value === "") {  
        alert("Please type your email the email feild.");  
        return false;  
    }  
    if(form1.age.value === "") {  
        alert("Please type your age the age feild.");  
        return false;  
    }  
    if(form1.gender.value === "") {  
        alert("Please type your gender the gender feild.");  
        return false;  
    }  
    if(form1.city.value === "") {  
        alert("Please type your city the city feild.");  
        return false;  
    }  
    return true;  
}
```

Comment: **return false** will stop the form from being submit while **return true** will submit the form. Based on your requirement you can do your custom work and then **return false**

Answer (score 0):

The href is the same page. Clicking the button might redirect before you run that script. Try returning false or something.

Comment: `#` href won't redirect to anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your save function checks some fields in a form in order to submit them. If so then the error isn't about the link or the submit, the problem is the way you are using variables. You can't just do city.value, you need to use document.getElementById('city').value. This will cause javascript to give you a "variable undefined" error and halt execution. The correct code would be:

```
function saveChanges() {
  var theCity = document.getElementById('city').value;
  var theState = document.getElementById('state').value;
  var theEmail = document.getElementById('email').value;
  var theAge = document.getElementById('age').value;
  var theGender = document.getElementById('gender').value;
  var theOther = document.getElementById('other').value;
    alert("theCity is: "+ theCity);
    alert("theState is: "+ theState);
    alert("theEmail is: "+ theEmail);
    alert("theAge is: "+ theAge);
    alert("theGender is: "+ theGender);
    alert("theOther is: "+ theOther);
}
window.onload=function (){
    document.getElementById('ok').onclick=saveChanges;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

**HTML**

```
<input type='text' id='city'> <br />
  <input type='text' id='state'> <br />
  <input type='text' id='email'> <br />
  <input type='text' id='age'> <br />

<hr>
<a href="#" id="ok" style="">Click here </a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**Javascript**

```
function id(e){
   return document.getElementById(e);
}

function saveChanges(){
   var city  = id('city').value,
       state = id('state').value,
       email = id('email').value,
       age   = id('age').value;

    alert("City : " + city + "\nState :" + state  +"\nEmail : " + email + "\n Age  : " + age);  

    return false;
}
window​.onload = function(){    
    document.getElementById("ok").onclick = saveChanges;
};​
```

***Demo*** : http://jsfiddle.net/Zjrd3/

Comment: Sorry, I wanted a button to do the same function as the link. I already have a link that does exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById` is not going to apply to more than one element. ID's should be unique.